# Excel Formula to return true false after searching for specific cells with blanks

Tags: excel

So I have this formula currently

=IFERROR(IF(MATCH(C1,test7!$B3:$B10,0),"1",),"0")

that corresponds to return a "1" or "0" value on a chart. But because the data is in different ranges some are between B3:B10 some are B13:B21 etc, I couldn't find a formula which will correlate with the IFERROR formula to return a 1 or 0. There would always be a 2 row gap between the ranges, eg B3:B10, B13:B21, B24:B40 etc.

Question is how do I incorporate the formula above to search and return "1" and "0" if my data has a two row gap and at random positions?

Sorry if it was explained poorly, it's my first time trying to do this on excel! I greatly appreciate all the help <3

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Give a try on below formula.

```
=--ISNUMBER(MATCH(E$1,INDEX($B$2:$B$19,MATCH($D2,$A$2:$A$19,0)):INDEX($B$2:$B$19,IFERROR(MATCH($D2+1,$A$2:$A$19,0),ROW($B$19)-ROW($B$1))),0))
```

[image]

> ***Edit:*** If your user id is not sequential number or it is text then can use below formula.

```
=LET(x,SCAN("",$A$2:$A$19,LAMBDA(a,b,IF(b="",a&b,b))),y,$B$2:$B$19,z,FILTER(y,x=$D2),--ISNUMBER(XMATCH(E$1,z,0)))
```

[image]

Comment: Hello Harun,

Your formula works like a charm but when I change the User ID to multiple numerical values the formula doesn't work anymore. May you have a look and let me know if there is a solution? Thanks - attached image above

Comment: Then use `=LET(x,SCAN("",$A$2:$A$19,LAMBDA(a,b,IF(b="",a&b,b))),y,$B$2:$B$19,z,FILTER(y,x=$D2),--ISNUMBER(XMATCH(E$1,z,0)))`

Comment: Hello Harun,

Greatly appreciate your help on another formula but when I try to input it again, the results are 0 only. I have attached an image above labelled "test1" for your convenience. Please let me know if I have done anything incorreactly. Thanks again :)

Comment: @Puffamix You do not show formula to your screenshot. Can you share a sample file via google drive and paste download link here in comment.

Comment: @Puffamix it is restricted. allow to download.

Comment: In case of number values (User ID) use `=LET(x,SCAN(0,$A$2:$A$3000,LAMBDA(a,b,IF(b="",a+b,b))),y,$B$2:$B$3000,z,FILTER(y,x=$D2),--ISNUMBER(XMATCH(E$1,z,0)))`. Also make sure you have `LET()` function to Excel version.

Comment: Harun you legend. Thank you so much!! Everything worked perfectly :)

Comment: @Puffamix Glad to know! If it works then tick mark the answer and upvote it to encourage.

Comment: Yes, I have definitely tick-marked it. Would you kindly explain the above formula step by step for future reference? Thanks :)